# How to send text file contents in email body with column alignment using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have a setup on server that will take care sending the reports from SQL records by mail using [wMailTo](http://www.jgaa.com/content/1/old_sites/july_2000/wmailto.htm) console application. But now my concern is that the mail body is not in proper column alignment and therefore it is very difficult to read in Outlook. The file `Report.txt` is in proper alignment. I am using the below line in batch script to send an email.

```
sqlcmd -S ErrorCode1 -E -i C:\Shared\Report.sql -o C:\Shared\Report.txt
findstr.exe /L /C:"DOWN" Report.txt 
if not errorlevel 1 ( 
    wmailto %dbemail% -s"%ServerName% DOWN Alert." -tReport.txt
)
```

Text file contains:

```
IPAddress       ErrorCode        Status       Time           
-----------     -----------      -------      ----------- 
127.0.0.1       0x1548SW581      FullError    12:00:40.03                      
127.0.0.2       0x1548SW5811258  PartialError 12:09:55.42
127.0.0.1       0x1548SW9878     No Error     12:00:40.03
```

Mail looks:

```
IPAddress       ErrorCode    Status       Time           
-----------     -----------      -------      ----------- 
127.0.0.1       0x1548SW581   FullError    12:00:40.03                      
127.0.0.2       0x1548SW5811258       PartialError 12:09:55.42
127.0.0.1       0x1548SW9878       No Error     12:00:40.03
```

Is there any other free application which take care of the column alignment?

Or is there any way that I can send mail in RichText to come over this issue?

I did tried the MORE Option but no luck

```
more /t1  report.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: How a plain text in an email looks like depends on email format (plain text, RTF or HTML), which font is defined by the receiver (plain text) or by you (RTF and HTML), and usage of right formatting tags (RTF and HTML). The default is usually a proportional font on which every character has its own width resulting in plain text email contents aligned just with spaces not containing special alignment tags is not looking good.

Comment: i have given more details and i dunno how to define the mail format in Wmailto.exe, is there any particular command to define, i request you to please help me and route me in proper direction

Comment: I suppose the text file contents are sent with a plain text email and I suppose further the receiver of the email has configured a fixed width font for viewing/editing plain text emails. And last I suppose the file `Report.txt` uses horizontal tab characters for data column alignments instead of spaces. In this case the different tab stop value of application used by you to view `Report.txt` and Outlook is the reason for getting the data displayed misaligned. In case all of my speculations are right, you need to replace the tabs by spaces before sending the lines from `Report.txt` by email.

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct, but i did make the changes in SQL Servermanagement Studio but still the report.txt is generating in TAB with indents, please help how to do it in query, i did Tools--> options-->Plain Text-->Tabs.

Comment: Or is there any way to convert the plain text to rich text is this will help, or else we can remove the tabs with spaces using the batch script. please guide me to correct path.

Comment: wMailTo does not support RTF file as input file for email body according to its documentation. So you need to read in the file `Results.txt` line by line for example with `for /F` and output the lines with having each tab character replaced by the right amount of spaces for a fine displayed plain text in sent email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `C:\Shared\Report.txt` contains for example:

```
IPAddress»    ErrorCode»        Status»        Time
-----------»  -----------»      -------»       -----------
127.0.0.1»    0x1548SW581»      FullError»     12:00:40.03
127.0.0.2»    0x1548SW5811258»  PartialError»  12:09:55.42
127.0.0.1»    0x1548SW9878»     No Error»      12:00:40.03
```

`»` and right number of spaces is used here as placeholder for a horizontal tab character really existing in the text file between the data columns.

For sending the text data with a plain text email it is necessary to convert the data for example to:

```
IP Address    Error Code        Status         Time
-----------   ---------------   ------------   -----------
127.0.0.1     0x1548SW581       FullError      12:00:40.03
127.0.0.2     0x1548SW5811258   PartialError   12:09:55.42
127.0.0.1     0x1548SW9878      No Error       12:00:40.03
```

The tabs are replaced by spaces and additionally the first two lines are slightly modified, too.

The batch code to achieve this is:

```
@echo off
sqlcmd.exe -S ErrorCode1 -E -i C:\Shared\Report.sql -o C:\Shared\Report.txt
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /C:"DOWN" C:\Shared\Report.txt
if errorlevel 1 goto Done

setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "TempFile=C:\Shared\Report.tmp"

echo IP Address    Error Code        Status         Time>"%TempFile%"
echo -----------   ---------------   ------------   ----------->>"%TempFile%"

for /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-5" %%A in ("C:\Shared\Report.txt") do (
    set "IpAddress=%%A             "
    set "IpAddress=!IpAddress:~0,11!"
    set "ErrorCode=%%B               "
    set "ErrorCode=!ErrorCode:~0,15!"
    if "%%C %%D" == "No Error" (
        set "Status=No Error    "
        set "Time=%%E"
    ) else (
        set "Status=%%C            "
        set "Status=!Status:~0,12!"
        set "Time=%%D"
    )
    echo !IpAddress!   !ErrorCode!   !Status!   !Time!>>"%TempFile%"
)

wmailto.exe %dbemail% -s"%ServerName% DOWN Alert." -t"%TempFile%"
del "%TempFile%"
endlocal

:Done
```

Command **FOR** uses by default spaces and tabs to split up a line into tokens. This is not perfect here because of status `No Error`. The code above takes this exception into account.

But there might be more such exceptions in file. For that reason it might be better to use just horizontal tab character as delimiter as demonstrated by the batch code below.

```
for /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1-4 delims=»" %%A in ("C:\Shared\Report.txt") do (
    set "IpAddress=%%A             "
    set "IpAddress=!IpAddress:~0,11!"
    set "ErrorCode=%%B               "
    set "ErrorCode=!ErrorCode:~0,15!"
    set "Status=%%C            "
    set "Status=!Status:~0,12!"
    echo !IpAddress!   !ErrorCode!   !Status!   %%D>>"%TempFile%"
)
```

**NOTE:** Character `»` after `delims=` in first line of **FOR** command must be replaced in batch file by a horizontal tab character for a working batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Works like a charm thanks and i also found a another way to send email in HTML Format via SQL , any way thanks a lot for your support.